# Drupal email variables not appearing

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Whenever a user registers an account, the automated emails (which I can set in `admin/config/people/accounts`) are not carrying over the defined variables for username, email, etc.

For example. Here's what I have set for one email:

*[user:name],*

*Thank you for registering at [site:name]. Your application for an account is currently pending approval. Once it has been approved, you will receive another e-mail containing information about how to log in, set your password, and other details.*

*-- [site:name] team*

Those variables in brackets just aren't appearing. The email sends as usual, but where those variables are, nothing gets inserted. Is there something I have to enable first?

Comment: Do you have the Token module installed and enabled?

Comment: No, I'll look into that.

Comment: I installed it and enabled it. Now getting weird PHP notices related to it and the problem persists

Comment: which drupal version you use ?

Comment: The first thing you should check is apache and Drupal logs. Then make sure no other module(s) overriding these mails

Comment: what are the PHP notices?

Comment: Please move this question to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ for a better chance of respone

Answer (score 1):

The token replacement in mails happen in line 2815 of user.module (modules/user/user.module). You can add the following line of code

```
drupal_set_message("Text: $text, Variables: " . print_r($variables, TRUE) . ", Language: $language);
```

before the line that says

```
return token_replace($text, $variables, array('language' => $language, 'callback' => 'user_mail_tokens', 'sanitize' => FALSE, 'clear' => TRUE));
```

That will tell you as messages what is happening with the token replacement issue. If you can post the messages that you see back here I can help solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have misconfiguration issues or losing sth .for seeing configs with html mail in [here](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail) ,
see [here](http://drupalcode.org/project/htmlmail.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/README.html)
also try updating it using update.php!

Answer (score 0):

-- READ FROM **PHP.NET** SPECIFICATIONS --,

- I THINK THAT BY DEFAULT, SOME HOST PROVIDERS DO NOT SUPPORT FEW PHP FILTERS (*OR LIKEWISE*), SO (ITS JUST AN ASSUMPTION !) MAY BE, **FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL** THAT IS USED TO REMOVE ALL CHARACTERS EXCEPT LETTERS, DIGITS AND !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~@.[], IS TURNED ON.
  SO JUST CHECK IT OUT !